# mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php

¿Podrían ayudarme con este error?

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/catalogo.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($Catalogo, $theValue): mysqli_escape_string($theValue);
// : mysql_escape_string($theValue)
  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given`
al ser llamado como función, el primer parametro debe de ser una variable que sea declarada como `$conexion = new mysqli(.....);`

en tu **if** tienes

```
$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($Catalogo, $theValue): mysqli_escape_string($theValue);
```

pero dentro de la función no conoce quien es `$Catalogo`, puedes pasarlo como parametro

Comment: hola de hecho ya pude resolverlo lo que realice fue :
`if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
global $catalogo;
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }`

  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($catalogo,$theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($catalogo,$theValue);

Comment: Javier, publica tu solución como una respuesta a tu pregunta y aceptala para que no esté en la fila de pendientes... saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví de este modo.

**Luego de la siguiente línea:**

```
 if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }
```

**Inserté este IF:**

```
 if (PHP_VERSION >= 7) {     // SI la versión de PHP es mayor o igual a 7.
    global $Catalogo;        // Hago global la variable 
  }
```

Eso fue suficiente.